# Laravel - Retrive row from DB as json when one column is in json format

Tags: json, laravel

I store my data in DB where one of column keep data as a json format.
When I try to retrieve row and response as json then I have that column as a string instead of json object.

DB:

> id | name | map_id | map_settings | created_at
>
> 1 | Europe | 2 | {"zoom":7,"minZoom":5,"maxZoom":9,"zoomControl":true,"disableDefaultUI":true,"center":"new google.maps.LatLng(51.954422144707960, 19.140930175781250)"} | 2018-08-19 05:19:50

PHP

```
$mapConfig = MapConfig::with(['places'])->where(['id'=>$id])->get();
    return response()->json($mapConfig);
```

Result

```
id: 1,
name: "Europe",
map_id: 2,
map_settings: "{\"zoom\":7,\"minZoom\":5,\"maxZoom\":9,\"zoomControl\":true,\"disableDefaultUI\":true,\"center\":\"new google.maps.LatLng(51.954422144707960, 19.140930175781250)\"}"
```

Why that map_settings is not in correct JSON format? And how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it (map_settings) by json_decode becausue it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [laravel attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) and convert your json to array, then it would work fine with response json function.